# Issues with AutoHotKey symbol pasting from GUI

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to AHK, and am trying to make a script that opens a GUI with a short list of commonly-used symbols that can be chosen, and then be automatically be pasted.

My code so far:

```
!+q::
Gui, Add, ListBox, w100 h100, vSymbolChoice, ™|©|°|π|☭|☢|⚠|ツ|•|Ω
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Submit 
Gui, Add, Button, default, Cancel
Gui, Show
return 

ButtonSubmit:
Gui, Submit
Sleep, 1000
Send, %SymbolChoice%
Gui, Destroy

ButtonCancel: 
Gui, Destroy
```

It creates the GUI and the `ListBox` but doesn't paste the symbol when I have it selcted and press submit.

Also, is there a better way to detect if a text field is selected than just waiting a second and hoping the user selected the field in that time?

Comment: See [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=57152) for detecting focus changes. But maybe you'd want to explain what exactly you're looking to do? Then I could maybe write a proper answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; auto-execute section
; create and show the Gui
Gui, Add, ListBox, w100 h130 vSymbolChoice, ™|©|°|π|☭|☢|⚠|ツ|•|Ω
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Submit
Gui, Add, Button,, Hide ; you can't have two default buttons on a Gui
Gui, Show
return

; Press Alt+Shift+Q to show the hidden Gui after ButtonSubmit or ButtonHide
!+q:: Gui, Show 

ButtonSubmit:
GuiControlGet, SymbolChoice ; get the control's contents stored in the variable SymbolChoice (retrieves the ListBox's current selection)
Gui, Submit ; saves the contents of this control to its associated variable SymbolChoice
SendInput, %SymbolChoice%
return

; Hide the Gui
ButtonHide: 
Gui, hide
return

; Press ESC or close the Gui to terminate the script
GuiClose:
Esc:: ExitApp
```

For details see [GUI](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) in the documentation.